# issue loading csv to hive table when some values contain ","

Tags: hive, hdfs

I am trying to load a csv in to the hive table and while loading is successful, the table is not loaded correctly due to "," in some column values. What is the best way to resolve this?

```
create table abc (col1 string, col2 int) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

CSV sample:-

```
col1      col2
abc,def   12
erfd      10


 load data inpath 'path_to_csv' into table abc;
```

The expected output is that the table is properly populated in hive like it is in csv.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following SERDE:

1. Sample table creation

   ```
   create table test_hive1(name String, id int)
   ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde';
   ```
2. Load data

   ```
   load data local inpath 'filepath' into table test_hive1;
   ```
3. Output

   ```
   select * from test_hive1;
   name    id
   abc 22
   cdf, def    23
   dsa 34
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**Use OpenCSV serde**

```
create table abc (col1 string, col2 int) row format
SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES 
("escapeChar" = ",") ;
```

load data into table using the command

```
 load data local inpath 'path_to_csv' into table abc;
```